# White space on top of my webpage

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me please? There is some white space between top of my page and div container and I have no clue why: http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/

@optimus203 I can see that my HTML is messed up when look at it in browser. But this is my header.php file, it seems to be ok. I'm quite a newbie and I'm trying to create wordpress + bootstrap theme. I have no idea what am I doing wrong... :(

```
 <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php wp_title('|',1,'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!--Styles -->
        <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Khula&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
      </head>

      <body>
      <div class="container-fluid kol">
```

Comment: There are some newline characters in the body:
`<body>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is all messed up. You had your head content in the body tag, and other issues.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> WTF Design</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--Styles -->
    <link href="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/wp-content/themes/mywtftheme/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Khula&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="WTF Design » główna Kanał z komentarzami" href="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/?feed=rss2&amp;page_id=5">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/wp-content/themes/mywtftheme/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?ver=4.1.1"></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.1.1">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/">
<link rel="shortlink" href="http://iwokolasinski.com/wtfq/">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid kol">    <h1>główna</h1>  
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Heading 1</h1>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Heading 2</h2>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Content</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;">Paragraph</p>

﻿    
      <footer>
        <p>footer</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question tho.

Comment: Have you tried to replace your code with what is above? Its creating the space because your structure is messed up.

Comment: I'm not the asker. And it is propably not the cause.

Comment: As Borislav Ivanov mentioned, you have newline characters between the <body> and <meta charset="utf-8"> tags. Deleting those will solve the issue. But it's also a good idea to have the correct infrastructure in place.

Comment: I removed the newline characters but it doesn't solve the problem... Why there is all head content between my body tags? In my header.php file head content is placed between head tags.

Comment: Looks like you updated. Adding this CSS rule shows that there is no longer space above your page:

    header#masthead { background:#f00; }

Answer (score 1):

That is the default settings of current browsers. 
You can override this by setting your CSS like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the end of your `<head>` section and it worked:

```
<style>
  body {
    margin-top:-25px;
  }
</style>
```